# Chrome extension won't work on HTTPS urls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, https

The chrome extension I developed works on every domain besides HTTPS ones.
I've tried setting matches like this: `"matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"]`.
But it still doesn't work.

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My App",
    "version": "0.01",
    "background": {
        "persistent":true,
        "page":"background.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js": ["app.js"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope. nothing...

Comment: Have you tried matching: "*://*/*"

Comment: @TobiasBeuving it won't let me use just `://*/*`, says the json file is not valid.

Comment: stackoverflow does not allow me to paste the asterix: * in front of the :

Comment: `"js": ["app.js"], "js": ["jquery.min.js"]` won't work. You probably want: `"js": ["jquery.min.js","app.js"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is awkward.
  Just had to change `permissions` from:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*"
]
```

To:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
]
```